# What is the significance of Heidegger's concept of Gewörfenheit (AKA throwness)?

Tags: heidegger

I don't know much about Heidegger but I happen to like this concept very much. The feeling that we are "thrown" into this world.

I'm taking a class on creative writing and wanted to write something about this. But before I actually do it, I wanted to be informed about Heidegger's use of the word, and what it means to the philosophical community

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently he was aware of Buddhism to some extent; for example, [In a study on the Buddhist and Taoist influences on Heidegger’s work, Reinhold May writes that Heidegger’s “direct contact with East Asian thought dates back at least as far as 1922” when he began conversations with several major Japanese thinkers.](http://www.openculture.com/2014/05/martin-heidegger-talks-philosophy-with-a-buddhist-monk.html)

Comment: @ChrisW true, but not sure why that's relevant. He tried to "translate" the *Daodejing* -- a project that didn't go so well, but he did have several Japanese students at different points.

Answer (score 3):

That's a really broad question of sorts. But *Gewörfenheit* which you render as thrownness refers to *Da-sein* (for our purposes you can just think of this as "human beings" ) state of already being the world. In other words, we don't start out at the view from nowhere.

There are some corollaries for Heidegger that follow from this:

1. Da-sein is always in motion propelled as it were.
2. Da-sein is in motion towards our its death (this is the ultimate possibility for *Da-sein*)
3. Da-sein is caught up in time.

Da-sein has no choice in any of this and just needs to figure out what it will do given this. For Heidegger, the answer is to be authentic about possibility #2 and understand our state in this way, accepting the limits of our existence...

Answer (score 2):

Below is a link to an Heidegger dictionary which has an entry for 'throwness' (p.218) and, it is a free downloadable pdf as well. Happy trails![http://www.olimon.org/uan/inwood-a_heidegger_dictionary.pdf][1]

Comment: Greetings, welcome to philosophy.se. If possible, we are looking for answers in themselves not links.

Comment: Now at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7578/fffa23aea0dd873cda63cdf53f1e3f8ad6b1.pdf